# How can I select a tab when changing a selected option?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How in Bootstrap 4 can I make the tabs switch when selecting a dropdown option?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you be more illustrative please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Made something according to what I understood from your question though it is described very roughly what you need. See if this can be helpful.

HTML:

```
<select class="nav-select">
      <option href="#home" selected>Home</option>
      <option href="#profile">Profile</option>
    </select>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('select.nav-select').on('change',function(){
   var selected_id=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('href');
  $('.tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('show active');
  $(selected_id).addClass('show active');
});
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but [Tab has methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tabs-methods) do do what you're doing manually. It's best to use them so that things stay in sync.